# Two ElGamal ciphertexts equivalence

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Is there a way to prove that two ElGamal ciphertexts encrypt the same message with different public keys without knowing the private keys?

The prover is the producer of both ciphertexts.

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, are those two ciphertexts encrypted to the same public key?  Are you asking whether the holder of the private key(s) can generate a zero-knowledge proof, or whether someone with only the public keys can deduce it?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions.